# Fabric automatically upload missing dSYMs

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

http://prntscr.com/b388sf

I constantly have this problem after iOS9 and am bored of it. I am using latest Xcode/Fabric/Swift with bitcode enabled. I have to go manually download dSYM from itunesconnect and upload it to fabric to make it work.

What am I doing wrong, how can I make it work automatically like its intended?

Answer (score 15):

Mike from Fabric here.

Using Bitcode will definitely make this problem happen more often, but there's a couple of ways handling it. You can automatically download the dSYMs using [Fastlane.tools](http://fastlane.tools) by running `fastlane refresh_dsyms` which will download the dSYMs from iTunesConnect and then upload them to Fabric. Reference for Fastlane's `refresh_dsyms` is here: https://krausefx.com/blog/download-dsym-symbolication-files-from-itunes-connect-for-bitcode-ios-apps

In practice, create a fastlane called: `refresh_dsyms`, with the following:

```
lane :refresh_dsyms do
  download_dsyms                  # Download dSYM files from iTC
  upload_symbols_to_crashlytics   # Upload them to Crashlytics
  clean_build_artifacts           # Delete the local dSYM files
end
```

Which will download the dSYMs from iTunesConnect and upload them to Fabric.

Alternatively,  you can run the Fabric `upload_symbols` script, but you would need to have manually download the dSYMs from iTunesConnect - this would only handle the upload. The command would be: `find <directory-to-search-for-dsyms> -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I \{\} /path/to/upload-symbols -a <api-key> -p <platform> \{\}`

Reference for upload_symbols is here: https://docs.fabric.io/ios/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols-script and

For the reason why this is happening, Apple is recompiling your app when Bitcode is enabled, so the dSYM is only generated on Apple's servers which prevents Fabric from uploading them automatically.

Comment: So just disabling bitcode will solve this issue without hassles?

Comment: That's pretty much what we've found. There are a few edge cases, but  Apple is recompiling your app on their servers, creating a new dSYMs, so there's no way for us to capture those dSYMs.

Comment: @MikeBonnell when I use this solution it works fine according our CI and everything is uploaded. ( Its a cron job that runs once a week ) but its running for a few weeks now and without result. It seems the dsyms are not processed by Fabric.

Comment: Hey Reshad - please email support(at)fabric(dot)io and include the dSYMs and bundle id of your app so we can look into this more.

Comment: @MikeBonnell can you please clarify? Should we call `upload_symbols_to_crashlytics` after `crashlytics` action? Or are dSYMs already there with uploading a build?